# Airflow - run DAG at start of data interval

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I would like to create a monthly dag that runs at the start of each month and which uses a logical date as the start of the same month (so e.g. March’s logical run date would actually run on March 1 instead of waiting until the end of the period (April 1)).
How to do this in Airflow? Can a custom timetable achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have a solution by defining my own custom monthly schedule in Airflow and basically setting the data interval start and ends to be the same at the start of each month.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).